# How to Join Two Tables an Update Only on SELECT Statement Without Applying any Update into Tables in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, psql

I have two tables in Oracle database called `tbl_genres` and `tbl_movies` theirs basic schema looks like this

**tbl_genres**

[image]

**tbl_movies**

[image]

Now what I need to have is updating the output only on **SELECT** statement without applying update into `tbl_movies` and getting a result like this

[image]

Comment: Look for `join`

Comment: Thanks for reply astentx but I do not want to have any data from `tbl_genres` on the output! my understanding from join is bringing both tables together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished using an INNER JOIN:

```
select t1.movie as Movie, t2.genre_name as Genre from tbl_movies as t1
inner join tbl_genres as t2 on t1.m_genre=t2.genreid;
```

This works by selecting the movie and genre columns, and joining them together on the basis of a common identifier (in this case, m_genre/genre_id).